# Spring Lemon dependency failing in POM

Tags: spring-lemon

I follow the spring lemon tutorial for using the spring lemon I included the Spring Lemon dependency but the spring lemon dependency cannot be downloaded, It says  "Missing artifact com.naturalprogrammer:spring" 
I have included the JitPack repository aswel, I still get that error.
I tried maven update , download source etc

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[spring-lemon tag]

Comment: Works fine in my machine. Anyone else getting the same error? A guess is that your maven repo could be corrupted -- you could try out deleting com/naturalprogrammer folder there, and then do maven -> update project on your prroject.

Comment: My project doesn't have com/naturalprogrammer folder. I did a maven ->update project, Still no effect, I wish i could get this to work

Comment: I'm not talking about a project folder, but about the local maven repo. I think its default location should be `.m2\repository` in your home folder. Assuming so, try deleting the `.m2\repository\com\naturalprogrammer` folder and do `maven -> update project` again.

Comment: Gave a closer look, there indeed was some DNS issue. Now back to normal. Thanks for reporting!